# Onvif Camera get current position

Tags: c#, onvif, preset

I have a simple application which allows me controlling PTZCameras.
My problem is getting the current camera position.
To do this I've used `var position = ptzClient.GetStatus(profile.token).Position` instruction.
If I set a new preset (using SetPreset method), **without moving the camera device**, its position results different from `status.Position`.
I think that the actual camera position is the `preset.PTZPosition` and not `status.Position` value.
How can I know the true camera value? And which position is `status.Position`?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you link to the library you are using that provides you the `ptzClient.GetStatus` method?

Comment: [OnvifPTZService](http://onvif.org/onvif/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl) provides me PTZ services